# Select distinct using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, class

I have a class list of class

```
public class LinqTest
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string value { get; set; }
}


List<LinqTest> myList = new List<LinqTest>();
myList.Add(new LinqTest() { id = 1, value = "a" });
myList.Add(new LinqTest() { id = 1, value = "b" });
myList.Add(new LinqTest() { id = 2, value = "c" });
```

I need to select only the distinct id's from that list.
ie, my resultant list should only contain

```
[{id=1,value="a"},{ id = 2, value = "c" }]
```

How can I do this with linq?

**Edit**

Input,

```
id      value
1        a
1        b
2        c
3        d
3        e
```

Out put should be,

```
id      value
1        a
2        c
3        d
```

ie, if there is a repetition of `id`, result should take the first occurrence only.

Comment: Why should the result contain `"a"` instead of `"b"`?

Comment: @Jodrell : It should contain the first value.

Answer (score 589, accepted):

```
myList.GroupBy(test => test.id)
      .Select(grp => grp.First());
```

Edit: as getting this `IEnumerable<>` into a `List<>` seems to be a mystery to many people, you can simply write:

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(test => test.id)
                   .Select(grp => grp.First())
                   .ToList();
```

But one is often better off working with the `IEnumerable` rather than `IList` as the Linq above is lazily evaluated: it doesn't actually do all of the work until the enumerable is iterated. When you call `ToList` it actually walks the entire enumerable forcing all of the work to be done up front. (And may take a little while if your enumerable is infinitely long.)

The flipside to this advice is that each time you enumerate such an `IEnumerable` the work to evaluate it has to be done afresh. So you need to decide for each case whether it is better to work with the lazily evaluated `IEnumerable` or to realize it into a `List`, `Set`, `Dictionary` or whatnot.

Comment: FYI: This won't work unless you convert it back to a list again. GroupBy().Select(First()) will generate an ienumerable and you'll get a conversion error.

Do this:
    myList.GroupBy(test => test.id)
      .Select(group => group.First()).ToList();

Comment: And you have to define newList. Then Set result to this newList. Otherwise grouping does not work. This worked for me. 
'List<LinqTest> newList = new List<LinqTest>();
newList  = myList.GroupBy(test => test.id)
      .Select(group => group.First());'

Comment: Hey yunus. Thanks for your little comment. I was able to get  my IEnumerable to work by using your code and changing List stuff:             IEnumerable<EDI_RAW_TCR> rows = from c in dc.EDI_RAW_TCRs
                                    where c.Batch_ID == 20830                      
                                   select c;

            IEnumerable<EDI_RAW_TCR> raws = rows; 
            raws = rows.GroupBy(t => t.LabID) .Select(group => group.First());

Comment: in C# it require .FirstOrDefault() instead of .First()

Comment: @Sruit, no it doesn't.

Comment: @Sruit, C# doesn't require this, but you EF may give you some headache if you try to do this, say, in the repository.

Answer (score 142):

Using [morelinq](https://morelinq.github.io/) you can use `DistinctBy`:

```
myList.DistinctBy(x => x.id);
```

Otherwise, you can use a group:

```
myList.GroupBy(x => x.id)
      .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: Didnt know about this package absolutely what was needed good man

Comment: Which is faster?

Comment: @MarkWardell: `DistinctBy` never existed in .NET. As I wrote in my answer, you need to use morelinq to get that functionality

Comment: Thank uou so much. Such interesting package.

Answer (score 63):

You should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` meaningfully, in this case to compare the ID:

```
public class LinqTest
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        LinqTest obj2 = obj as LinqTest;
        if (obj2 == null) return false;
        return id == obj2.id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Distinct`:

```
List<LinqTest> uniqueIDs = myList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 30):

```
myList.GroupBy(i => i.id).Select(group => group.First())
```