# Remove every first element of grouped collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a collection of elements and some of these elements are duplicating. I need to extract all records but only the first record if the record is one of a duplicate set.

I was able to group the elements and find all elements that have duplicates, but how to remove every first element of a group?

```
var records = 
             dbContext.Competitors
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Email)
                       .Select(x => new { Properties = x, 
                               Count = x.Key.Count() })
                       .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
                       .ToList();
```

EDIT: Seems like it's impossible to accomplish this task with EF, because it fails to translate the desired linq expression to SQL. I'll be happy if someone offer different approach.

Comment: Could you try fixing your query so that you do not get duplicate elements into your collection?  It's easier to solve problems as the root cause rather than later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406242/select-distinct-using-linq

Answer (score 4):

To exclude the first record from each email-address group with more than one entry, you could do this:

```
var records = dbContext.Competitors
              .GroupBy(x => x.Email)
              .SelectMany(x => (x.Count() == 1) ? x : x.OrderBy(t=>t).Skip(1))
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, but the condition is to get all records, except the first of a dulicate set. With your solution i get just the first record of each group and i want to exclude it.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question ("I need to extract all records but only the first record if the record is one of a duplicate set"). Try my edited code.

Comment: Now i get `NotSupported Exception - The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.`

Comment: Oh, ok; I didn't know about that. I assume you can just add an OrderBy before the skip, then. See edit.

Comment: It seems EF fails to translate this expression into SQL. I've found similar issues in StackOverflow. I'll search for another solution. Thanks for your help anyways! +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the logic :

***Group** by a property > **Select** every Group > (Possibly) **Sort** that > **Skip** first one*

This can be turned into some linq code like this :

```
//use SelectMany to flat the array
var x = list.GroupBy(g => g.Key).Select(grp => grp.Skip(1)).SelectMany(i => i);
```