# Getting count of duplicate items in a List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, count, duplicates

I am trying to get the count for the most common duplicate item in a list.

So far, I have:

`List<string> brandList = new List<string>();`

which contains `5` different soft drink brands, and the count is `100`. I need to find out which brand has the most duplicates in the list and count how many duplicates there are.

Comment: (Duplicate?) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406242/select-distinct-using-linq

Comment: @cdslnte He needs the number of duplicates, not the distinct values.

Comment: That's not C# or at least not compiling

Comment: That gets rid of duplicates, not what im looking for. but thanks anyway..

Comment: I´m voting to close this question as its unclear what OP really needs. New requirements are coming every second...

Comment: how hard is it for you to give me code that gives me the frequency the duplicate items in a list in visual studio C# windows forms application code that is NOT linq ? but in basic format? lol

Answer (score 4):

Presuming that your pseudo code actually was:

```
List<Brand> brandList=new List<Brand>();
// fill list
```

and your `Brand` class either overrides `Equals`+`getHashCode` or has a property like `BrandID` which is the identifier. N youow want to get the count of the most popular brand, you can use LINQ:

```
var mostPopularBrand = brandList.GroupBy(b => g.BrandID)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => new { BrandID = g.Key, Count =  g.Count()})
    .First();

Console.WriteLine("Most poular brand: {0} Count: {1}", 
                   mostPopularBrand.BrandID, mostPopularBrand.Count);
```

**Update**: If it's actually a `List<string>`(question was edited):

```
var mostPopularBrand = brandList.GroupBy(str => str)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => new { Brand = g.Key, Count =  g.Count()})
    .First();
```

Comment: thats not for visual studio ?? :(

Comment: @chersharp: it's for C#. You can use LINQ if you use at least Visual Studio 2008(.NET 3.5).

Comment: i have to use windows forms application, do you think you could tell me how to do it on there?

Comment: @chersharp: i don't see how it is related that it's winforms. The issue is not related to gui controls.

Comment: i mean the coding format, i have to do it the simple way not Linq

Comment: @chersharp: you need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the code file, then you are able to use Linq extension methods like `Enumerable.GroupBy`. Btw, is it really a `List<string>`?

Comment: Yup i know that, but im at uni and we are not allowed to do our work that way

Comment: yes it is list <string> it removed the '<' for some reason when i posted it :O  haha

Answer (score 3):

Your code d*oesn't compile*. Providing that you mean `List<String>` as a storage of brands:

```
  var ListbrandList = new List<String>() {
    "Cola",
    "Juice",
    "Cola",
    "Water",
    "Milk",
    "Water",
    "Cola",
  };

  var result = ListbrandList
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(item => new {
         Name = item.Key,
         Count = item.Count()
       })
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Count)
    .ThenBy(item => item.Name);

  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(item => String.Format("{0} appears {1} time(s)", item.Name, item.Count)));
```

you'll have `report` as

```
  Cola appears 3 time(s)
  Water appears 2 time(s)
  Juice appears 1 time(s)
  Milk appears 1 time(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = brandList
            .Distinct()
            .GroupJoin(brand,
            k => k,
            b => b,
            (k, b) => new { BrandName = k, Count = b.Count() });

// An usage could be...

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} Brand has {1}", r.BrandName, r.Count);
}
```

Without LinQ:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var brand in brandList)
{
    if (!result.ContainsKey(brand))
    {
        var count = brandList.FindAll(x => x.Equals(brand)).Count;
        result.Add(brand, count);
    }
}

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Brand has {1}", r.Key, r.Value);
}
```

Comment: I am on VISUAL STUDIO C# Windows forms application......
How do you get the count for the number of times an item appears in a list???????
because i have no idea of that other form of coding yet

Comment: You have to include this in your file: `using System.Linq;` Then you will have the Count() extension method. The Count (without parenthesis) is a property of the List class.

Comment: Ohh ok, and then i would be able to type it in as you said?

Comment: Yes, I used that code without troubles.

Comment: do you know it in the other format, without using linq?

Comment: check out the answer again

Comment: That still has LINQ-code within...

Comment: yes it still has linq

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but I'm not using the methods of LinQ in the answer below of my first one. I don't have `System.Linq` in my imports.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
var res = brandList.GroupyBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new {Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count});
```

Now you have a list containing the actual drink-number and the count for this number.

EDIT: Getting the brand with most count is now easy, e.g. by using:

```
var mostPopular = res.Single(x => x.Count == res.Max(y => y.Count));
```

EDIT2: Without LINQ the following might work, which is way longer and more complicated:

```
// get the count for every brand

Dictionary<string, int> res = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var x in brands)
{
    if (!res.ContainsKey(x)) res[x] = 0;
    res[x]++;
}

// now get the max count

int currentMax = 0;
string key = "";
foreach (var kv in res)
{
    if (kv.Value > currentMax)
    {
        currentMax = kv.Value;
        key = kv.Key;
    }
}
```

Now the `key` should contain the brand with highest `Count`.

Comment: do you know how to do it in c# without doing it in linq?

Comment: You should have mentioned that within your question. Wait a few minutes...

Comment: i didnt even know what linq was until every answer was written in it, and still your second answer is not written in basic c# coding that i want

Comment: Sure it is, compiles on .NET 3.5 (even on 2.0) also without LINQ.  So what is your error here?

Comment: im sure it is right but the style of coding youre writing it in is not the one i know, and im not allowed to use it in my work, i am just using original coding

Comment: WHAT EXACTLY are you not allowed to do as this IS basic C#. What do you mean by "original coding"?

Comment: well mine has int, double, bool, all that,  not var? not GroupBy?

Comment: i mean just basic original style of coding

Comment: you may simply replace the `var` keyword by the actual type, although that IS basic C#. Just use VS to see what the actual type behind `var` is. Also there is no `GroupBy` within the last code.

Comment: string[] popularBrands = { "Cola", "Pepsi" };

        int[] quantities = new int[popularBrands.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < popularBrands.Length; i++)
        {
            quantities[i] = lst.Count(r => r.ToUpper() == popularBrands[i].ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("{0}  :   {1}", popularBrands[i], quantities[i]); 
        }
`

Comment: thaats the kind of code that im looking for

Comment: You should definitivly write all this stuff to your question to let other users know your actual requeirements. Furthermore if you already HAVE the code you´re looking for why ask here?

Comment: i just copied and pasted it from the comments on this post? its in the right format but its wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do group using LINQ by Elements and calculate count

```
var groupedList = from l in ListbrandList
    group l by l into grp
    select new { key = grp.Key, cnt = grp.Count()};
```

Then you will have group by key (Element) and value (Count)

Answer (score 0):

To count element with specific value in a list use :

```
int quantity = lst.Count(r => r == "Cola");
```

Example :

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>()
{
    "Sprite",
    "Cola",
    "Sprite",
    "Sprite",
    "Cola",
    "Sprite",
    "Sprite",
    "Cola",
    "Pepsi",
    "Sprite",
    "Pepsi",
    "Sprite",

};

string[] popularBrands = { "Cola", "Pepsi" };

int[] quantities = new int[popularBrands.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < popularBrands.Length; i++)
{
    quantities[i] = lst.Count(r => r.ToUpper() == popularBrands[i].ToUpper());
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  :   {1}", popularBrands[i], quantities[i]); 
}
```

Output

```
Cola : 3
Pepsi : 2
```

P.S.

About this code    `r => r.ToUpper() == popularBrands[i].ToUpper()` :
r is variable that holds a value from our list (that are taken one by one). We also use ToUpper() to make sure that our check is case insensitive.

So we basically loop through the collection taking values out of it one by one. Each time we put value to `r` variable and check if this variable satisfies condition. If so - we count it, if not - we just move to next value.

Comment: what does r => r mean?

Comment: @chersharp r is a variable that contains value taken one by one from your list. I updated my record to explain it.

Comment: thanks @Fabjan what does this '=>' mean??

Comment: Read this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-minutes