# Order By on specific column

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get the distinct records

```
var records = (from entry in db.Table1
               select new
               {
                   RowID = entry.RowID,
                   FirstName = entry.First,
                   LastName = entry.Last,
                   Restricted = (entry.Prohibited == null || entry.Prohibited == "False") ? "Restricted" : "Not Restricted"
               }).ToList();
```

Here RowID is an primary key. I want to get the distinct First and Last Name.

For example:

```
 RowID  First  Last Prohibited ...
  1     A       B     False
  2     A       B     False
  3     A       B     False
  4     Z       Y     True
  5     Z       Y     True
```

What I am trying to get here is:

```
 RowID  First   Last  Prohibited
 1      A       B     False
 4      Z       Y     True
```

How can I get it?

Comment: What does getting the distinct first and last name have to do with "Order By"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var records = (from entry in db.Table1
               group entry by new {entry.First, entry.Last} into g
               let entry = g.FirstOrDefault()
               select new
               {
                   RowID = entry.RowID,
                   FirstName = entry.First,
                   LastName = entry.Last,
                   Restricted = (entry.Prohibited == null || entry.Prohibited == "False") ? "Restricted" : "Not Restricted"
               }).ToList();
```

By grouping the items by the combined first and last name, and then only taking the first item in each group, you effectively ensure that you're getting distinct items based on those values.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do in this way:

```
var records = 
    (from entry in db.Table1
        select new {
            FirstName = entry.First,
            LastName = entry.Last,
            Restricted = (entry.Prohibited == null || entry.Prohibited == "False") ? "Restricted" : "Not Restricted"
        }).Distinct();
```

If you want the rowID also, you can read [select-distinct-using-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406242/select-distinct-using-linq).

Comment: but I need RowID as well.

Comment: ok, you can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406242/select-distinct-using-linq 
It's a duplicate question.